# Suppressing the removal of leading zeros in numeric data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, datatypes

I initially declared the data type of the columns for some of the tables I am working on as `NUMERIC`. Because of that, leading zeros are being removed.  Is there anyway to suppress this behavior?  I need to preserve the leading zeros, since `08` should be considered different from `0000008`.

One solution is to changing the definition of the table and changing the `numeric` to `varchar` datatype.

Is there any other way to achieve this without changing the table structure?

Comment: You are confusing data and presentation. Numeric are always precise to their last decimal, the way you see them is based on some presentation rule of the tool you are using

Comment: If `08` is considered different from `0000008`, then they are not numbers. Or more accurately, they might be numbers - if you define operations (i.e. addition, subtraction, etc) on them - but they won't be the common numbers (integers) we know.

Answer (score 1):

Retaining leading zeros for numeric data types is not possible.  Since you appear to be using this column as a non-numeric identifier, you should consider using a varchar column of appropriate length.

If the maximum length you're willing to accept in the table is 11 characters, and the value is always required, I would define the column like this:

```
someCol varchar(11) NOT NULL
```

The column will then differentiate between `08` and `000008`, and the leading zeros will be retained.